# Can cURL show redirect response body?

Tags: curl

I make a cURL HTTP GET request which gets a redirect response containing body.
With verbose cURL output I can see in the output:

> - Ignoring the response-body

I would like to see the response body even if a response is a redirect (let's say it's 301).

Is it possible to make cURL behave the way I want?
Reading through cURL man hasn't helped me to find an answer.
Maybe I missed something in the man.

Comment: At least If you don't ask curl to follow the direct, it will show it to you.

Comment: @DanielStenberg, great hint! In my underlying case it doesn't solve my certain problem that led to asking this question as the redirect there is not the first in the series of redirects. But I consider your comment to be an answer to the question as it's stated. Please create an answer in order I could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, curl does not show the response body when it follows a redirect and it does not have any option to do so. It then only shows the final response body, the one that is not redirected.

You can disable the redirect following and then you will see the response body.